# iron-list data binding won't update when array is changed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an array of objects one-way bound in an `<iron-list>` (e.g. `[[myArray]]`). I update the array with a totally new version of the array via `this.set("myArray", items)`. My issue is that the `<iron-list>` still shows the original array values. I know that this is a data-binding issue, but I thought that the `this.set` will auto notify. To further confuse me, whenever I use `this.push` the new items are correctly appended to the `<iron-list>`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug, please post your code.

Comment: I just discovered that the <iron-list> does indeed update the binding. However, the reason it only displays the data whenever I resize the screen. I am thinking that I have not implemented the IronResizeBehavior correctly. Once I figure that part out, I will post the solution - as well as my code.